# ExtJS Grid: Cell Editing: Blank cell if value entered is <SAMPLE>

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid

I am facing this issue while using editors in grid.
And I am finding this in almost all the grid examples that I found on net.
In a grid having editor such as textfield, try entering a value like `<SAMPLE>`.
Moment you go out of focus, a blank cell is displayed on the grid.
But if you again select it for editing, the actual entered text is retained.

Try it here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

I know this has to do with the html encoding/decoding and can be handled in the edit event.
But I feel this should have been handled internally by the grid.

Please suggest a better solution if any? I need to show such data in my grid, so it's a genuine request.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to escape such data on input, but rather do it on output. That way the user's input remains unchanged in your data storage. I assume that is the reason why the grid does not handle this itself. Also, it would not be possible to use HTML on a grid column if you actually wanted to.

Personally I provide a [renderer](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) on the grid column which escapes the value:

```
renderer: function(value) {
    return Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(value);
}
```

You can also do that for all grid columns by default with an override:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, {
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        this.callOverridden(arguments);

        if ('gridcolumn' === this.xtype && false === this.renderer) {
            this.renderer = function(value) {
                return Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(value);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

This will add such a renderer to all columns which do not have a renderer already provided in the config (in that case this renderer will need to take care of it).

Answer (score 0):

I found this as well whenever I had a grid where the cell value was `<Enter New Value>`.

It turned out that grid does not escape the cell values to protect itself from getting confused regarding HTML tags.

Lost a whole day on this thinking I had a model/store problem.  Read more about it here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232292-Escaping-HTML-characters-in-editable-grids

A workaround is here:

http://non-stop-ext.blogspot.com/2013/02/gridpanel-with-special-characters-and.html